# Equivalent of matplotlib's fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0) in Julia/Plots

Tags: julia, plots.jl, julia-plots

I am trying to draw a graph using Plots package in Julia and save it to SVG. While plotting two or more subplots one below the other is trivial in Plots (with the help of Layouts), I found it extremely difficult to make the subplots stick to each other. In matplotlib, it's easy: `fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0)`

What is the equivalent of this in Julia/Plots.

Here is what I hope to achieve:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the PythonPlot() backend? It claims to have all the functionality of matplotlib, as it is apparently a 1:1. https://docs.juliaplots.org/latest/backends/#[PythonPlot](https://github.com/stevengj/PythonPlot.jl)

Comment: @JonathanF. Thank you. This might be what I am looking for. I'll let you know if it works. :)